# template tag innerHTML breaks script tags

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

I'm trying to run a string of HTML through the HTML parser which contains `<tr>` elements. Using the normal HTML parser the `<tr>` elements would disappear because you can't create them outside of a `<table>` element. So I tried to use a `<template>` element and use `innerHTML`, since template tags don't have the same restrictions and can create the `<tr>` elements just fine. This worked pretty well and I was able to create the elements just fine.

```
var html = '<tr><td>foo</td></tr><tr><td>bar</td></tr>';
var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(template.content);
```

However, later on I tried to do the same thing using `<script>` tags instead of table rows, but when the template is added to the body, the script tag doesn't run.

```
var html = '<script>alert("hello");</script>';
var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(template.content);  // doesn't execute the script
```

But if I were able to create a script tag and append it to the template it would work.

```
var template = document.createElement('template');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = 'alert("hello");';
template.content.appendChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(template.content);  // does execute the script
```

Does anyone know why using `innerHTML` breaks script tags for templates (style tags also work fine using this method)?

Comment: Found a question similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: Ah, I've been searching around for specifically for problems with template innerHTML, didn't think to look it as an innerHTML problem. Thanks for that.